# Rails application MYSQL error nginx

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have deployed my application with nginx (maxime-mazet.agency) but I have a problem when I setup the application (create config ect..) Rails write one error

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

[image]

But I have written the good password in the configuration :/

Comment: It would be better if you pasted the error message directly in the question instead of linking to an image. Make sure all your config in `database.yml` (that means not just password) is correct.

Comment: `default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: ****
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
I think is correct the socket is good the password and username correct

Comment: When I wrote about pasting the error message in your question, I didn't mean pasting the path to this image on your local machine, it's pointless. 

You don't have database specified in your configuration (which, BTW, you also should include in question, not in comment).

Answer (score 0):

You have to try the following which is setup me for my RoR application.

Login to the console

```
$ ssh root@ip_address
```

Then setup MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

To find MySQL server info:

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql;
=> mysql -u root -p
mysqladmin -u root -p password #=> password it's your own
mysql -u root
```

If successfully created with command then update your `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  database: project_dev
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Inside application folder run

```
$ bundle install
$ rake db:create
$ rake db:migrate

$ sudo systemctl restart mysql
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

And then run the application.

Hope to help

Comment: The bug is always here :/
When I write the rake command this is good the database is create and the migration is good